Avoiding Merge In Pandas
I have a data frame that looks like this :

I want to group the data frame by #PROD and #CURRENCY and replace TP with the contents of the Offshore data in the Loc column Without creating two data frames and joining them.
The final output will look something like:

I was able to create the output by splitting the data frame into two (Onshore  and Offshore ) and then creating a join on #PROD and #CURRENCY. However, I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this ?
The Code for the Dataframe is :
import pandas as pd
data=[['Offshore','NY','A','USD','ABC_USD'],['Onshore','BH','A','USD',''],                  ['Onshore','AE','A','USD',''],\
     ['Offshore','NY','A','GBP','GBP_ABC'],['Onshore','BH','A','GBP',''],                           ['Onshore','AE','A','GBP',''],\
     ['Onshore','BH','A','EUR',''],['Onshore','AE','A','EUR','']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Loc', 'Country','#PROD','#CURRENCY','TP'])
df


Reopened: Because we need to filter where Loc is Offshore, not just get the TP value.

I think a merge is the most faithful and cleanest approach. It doesn't require to sort the data, nor to worry about side effects of groupby.

I think a merge is the most straightforward and efficient way to do this:
df['TP'] = df[cols].merge(df[df['Loc'].eq('Offshore')], how='left')['TP'].values

No need to sort, no need to worry about which values are initially present.
Alternatively:
cols = ['#PROD', '#CURRENCY']
s = (df[cols].reset_index().merge(df[df['Loc'].eq('Offshore')])
     .set_index('index')['TP']
    )
df.loc[s.index, 'TP'] = s

Output:
        Loc Country #PROD #CURRENCY       TP
0  Offshore      NY     A       USD  ABC_USD
1   Onshore      BH     A       USD  ABC_USD
2   Onshore      AE     A       USD  ABC_USD
3  Offshore      NY     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
4   Onshore      BH     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
5   Onshore      AE     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
6   Onshore      BH     A       EUR      NaN
7   Onshore      AE     A       EUR      NaN


You can use groupby then transform to get the first value of TP column where Loc is Offshore.
I sort the DataFrame beforehand to have the Offshore values above the Onshore values.
Try:
df['TP'] = (
    df.sort_values('Loc')
    .groupby(['#PROD', '#CURRENCY'])['TP']
    .transform('first')
    )
print(df)

Output:
        Loc Country #PROD #CURRENCY       TP
0  Offshore      NY     A       USD  ABC_USD
1   Onshore      BH     A       USD  ABC_USD
2   Onshore      AE     A       USD  ABC_USD
3  Offshore      NY     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
4   Onshore      BH     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
5   Onshore      AE     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
6   Onshore      BH     A       EUR         
7   Onshore      AE     A       EUR  


You can use this:
df["TP"] = (
    df.sort_values("Loc")  # ensure Offshore comes before Onshore
    .replace("", np.nan)  # replace "" with nan so it can be forward filled
    .groupby(["#PROD", "#CURRENCY"])["TP"]
    .ffill()
    .fillna("")
)

        Loc Country #PROD #CURRENCY       TP
0  Offshore      NY     A       USD  ABC_USD
1   Onshore      BH     A       USD  ABC_USD
2   Onshore      AE     A       USD  ABC_USD
3  Offshore      NY     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
4   Onshore      BH     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
5   Onshore      AE     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
6   Onshore      BH     A       EUR         
7   Onshore      AE     A       EUR         


A generic solution that would work for any number of variables can be achieved using something like this:
group_variables = ["#PROD", "#CURRENCY"]
target_variable = "TP"
groups = df.groupby(group_variables)
for location, value in groups[target_variable].apply(lambda x: "".join(x)).items():
    condition = pd.concat([df[var].eq(v) for var, v in zip(group_variables, location)], axis=1).all(axis=1)
    df.loc[condition, (target_variable)] = value

Output:
        Loc Country #PROD #CURRENCY       TP
0  Offshore      NY     A       USD  ABC_USD
1   Onshore      BH     A       USD  ABC_USD
2   Onshore      AE     A       USD  ABC_USD
3  Offshore      NY     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
4   Onshore      BH     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
5   Onshore      AE     A       GBP  GBP_ABC
6   Onshore      BH     A       EUR         
7   Onshore      AE     A       EUR      

